# Dynamic Memory allocation fault

Tags: c++, c++14

The program given below was created to use dynamically allocated memory....

But the program eventually crashes after adding more elements in the array.

This code clearly shows the concept used and error recieved.

**So Is there no way to extend the size of the dynamically allocated array as here my sample program wants more size after the memory has been allocated**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;  char ch='y';
    cout<<"Enter size of array: ";
    cin>>n;
    int *arr = new int[n];
    cout<<"Enter elements: ";
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i) cin>>arr[i];

    // above code works fine, the below creates problem

    while(ch=='y')
    {   n++;  cout<<"Enter 1 more element: ";   cin>>arr[n];
        cout<<"Want to enter more? ";       cin>>ch;
    }
    cout<<"All elements are: "; 
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    cout<<arr[i]<<"  ";

    delete []arr;
    return 0;
}
```

This is what valgrind shows

```
==5782== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5782== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5782== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5782== Command: ./ec
==5782== 
Enter size of array: 2
Enter elements: 
1
2
Enter 1 more element: 3
==5782== Invalid write of size 4 
==5782==    at 0x4F3A890: std::istream::operator>>(int&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
==5782==    by 0x108BC7: main (in /home/user1/ec)
==5782==  Address 0x5b8350c is 4 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==5782==    at 0x4C3089F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5782==    by 0x108B2A: main (in /home/user1/ec)
==5782== 
Want to enter more? y
Enter 1 more element: 4
Want to enter more?
```

**The above shown errors by valgrind increases when the concept is used in any big program....**

Comment: What is the type of `item` variable?

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: You do `for(int i = n;` and then you do: `arr[i]`. This is an out of bounds access, the last valid index is `n - 1`

Comment: `n+=1;` `n` keeps getting bigger. The allocated array does not. This big bombad not good idea.

Comment: Codeblocks has a decent front end for the GDB debugger. Debuggers are quite possibly the greatest programmer productivity tools you will ever encounter, so the sooner you get familiar with using them , the sooner you can start reaping the benefits.

Comment: The array created by `new int[n]` has a fixed size equal to the value that `n` had *at the time the array was created*. Under no circumstance can that array's size change.

Comment: @François  The previous code was really unclear.... but this code is what i m asking. How can i increase the size of any dynamically allocated array.  And since the user might enter any desired no. of elements so, its not good to put the array on stack, that's why i dynamically allocate, but encounters errors.

Comment: @root-user It's not possible to resize an array in c++. You must create a new array with the desired size and copy of the values from the old array. It's better to just use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which does all this for you.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux would you please give a sample code only showing a simple use of std::vector which should satisfy what you are saying.

Comment: @root-user https://www.google.com/search?q=std+vector+tutorial Edit : After reviewing the top hits, c++ tutorials are generally absolutely terrible...

Comment: so i think you looked upon the edited code. so can you figure out what's wrong with the above code, or that's the same problem . Am i right?

Comment: @root-user why don't you use a std::vector? it does the reallocation automatically when you add new elements.

Comment: @MikevanDyke  i wasn't aware of that , but now i can .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `n` keeps growing, but your array does not.

This code invokes undefined behavior, which thankfully caused a segfault for you:

```
while(ch=='y')
{   n++;  cout<<"Enter 1 more element: ";   cin>>arr[n];
    cout<<"Want to enter more? ";       cin>>ch;
}
```

`arr` has only been allocated to store `n` elements. Simply writing past the end will not automatically reallocate. You're looking for a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which will additionally save you the hassle of explicitly allocating/deallocating anything.

You can accomplish what you want like so (untested):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;  char ch='y';
    cout<<"Enter size of array: ";
    cin>>n;
    std::vector<int> arr(n);
    cout<<"Enter elements: ";
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i) cin>>arr[i];

    //...

    while(ch=='y')
    {   n++;  cout<<"Enter 1 more element: ";
        int tmp;
        cin>>tmp;
        arr.emplace_back(tmp)
        cout<<"Want to enter more? ";       cin>>ch;
    }
    cout<<"All elements are: "; 
    for(int element : arr)
       cout<< element <<"  ";

    return 0;
}
```

- We initialize the vector to store `n` elements

  - this allows us to say `cin >> arr[i]` at the start
- We use `emplace_back` for each additional item

  - this will cause the vector to automatically allocate enough new memory for us
  - and the allocation will happen logarithmically so we generally don't need to worry about performance loss

Comment: Thanks , the above code is what i need . just need to place    "arr.emplace_back(tmp);" instead of     "arr.emplace_back(tmp)" (without semicolons)